# Add a polygon as a clip parameter for WMS and WCS layer in Datacube OWS

Tags: python, clip, open-data-cube, ows

I am trying to add a clip as a parameter for a WMS and WCS URL end point, but couldn't clip based on a polygon.
Adding bbox for WCS endpoint returns the bounding box, not the exact polygon as the name suggests. Does datacube OWS have capability to add clip, as a parameter and pass WKT geometry of polygon or any format which can return clipped WMS and WCS data?

Example:

```
"service": "WMS",
"version": "1.3.0",
"request": "GetMap",
"layers": product_name,
 "width": "150",
"height": "150",
"crs": "EPSG:4326",
"bbox": "-43.28507087113431,146.18504300790977,-43.07072582535469,146.64289867785524",
"format": "image/png",
"exceptions": "XML",
"time": "2021-12-31",
```

Similarly, can I add a parameter like clip and add polygon?

```
"clip": POLYGON ((-13.648 122.999, -13.648 123.886, -15.464 123.886, -15.464 122.999, -13.648 122.999))
```

Comment: You can't clip a WMS with a polygon as a parameter

Answer (score 0):

The clip parameter is not supported by datacube-ows.

You can create a feature request issue for it on GitHub - but unless you can point to the OGC specification that defines the behaviour for the parameter it is unlikely to be implemented - I'm pretty sure it's not in the core WMS and WCS standards.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it myself yet, however, it seems that a WPS intermediate *may* be able to do that via the `CropCoverage` process. The host for WPS can be a GeoServer instance.